# Pandas Module: Works in PyCharm but not Terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I've written a python script (called python_script.py) in PyCharm that relies on the pandas module. The thing is, when I run the script in PyCharm, it works perfectly. But when I call it in terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sub_directory/python_script.py", line 9, in <module>
import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Comment: The error comes from your Python installation not having pandas installed. I haven't used PyCharm so I'm not positive, but it could be using its own Python installation. Try running `import sys; print sys.executable` in PyCharm and the Python interpreter in your terminal and see if they give you the same result

Comment: @BrettPatterson Thanks. I did as you said and the results are indeed different. For terminal I get "/Users/home/anaconda/bin/python" and in PyCharm I get "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python". Is there a way I can use this to find a solution?

Comment: The explanation is a little long for a comment, so I'll post an answer

Comment: @BrettPatterson Pandas is installed in terminal too. And Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install pandas into your anaconda installation by doing `conda install pandas` at the terminal. That's probably the easiest solution, but you could also use the other Python installation like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents‌​/MacOS/Python python_script.py
```

You could also create an alias within your terminal so that `python` would point to the system python installation. To do that you can put the line

```
alias python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents‌​/MacOS/Python
```

in your `~/.bash_profile`

(For reference: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/create-aliases-in-bash-profile-to-assign-shortcuts-for-common-terminal-commands/)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to install pandas using condo install pandas. It did install, but it still didn't work.

Comment: But the second option worked perfectly - (i.e. I created an alias and it solved the problem). Many Thanks!